# iBeacon devices scan and retrieve minor, major, uuid params

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Does anyone know if it's possible on iOS to scan the network and then discover all iBeacons devices? After the scan is completed I would like to get for each device the real uuid, minor and major values and check throughout a web service if that particular configuration is saved in my database.

I know that generally on iOS you have to know the proximityUUID and listen to a region using the Beacons API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only possible to scan a network for predefined beacon. A beacon region looks for devices whose identifying information matches the information you provide. When that device comes in range, the region triggers the delivery of an appropriate notification. see CLBeaconRegion class [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeaconRegion_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes android has a third party library that searches with wildcard, library link [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/documentation.html)

Comment: hard to say from doc, worth a try